# Yii2 pagination change style

Tags: css, pagination, yii2

How can I change css for pagination? 
I have code :

```
echo LinkPager::widget([
'pagination' => $pages,
'activePageCssClass'=>'act',
]);
```

and act class in my css:

```
.act{
    color:red;
 }
```

But it doesn't work. 
What options I must write for it?

Comment: Does the link has the class `act`? Can you inspect it using firebug?

Answer (score 11):

This is full configuration for Pagination

```
<?php
LinkPager::widget([
    'pagination' => $pages,
    //Css option for container
    'options' => ['class' => ''],
    //First option value
    'firstPageLabel' => '&nbsp;',
    //Last option value
    'lastPageLabel' => '&nbsp;',
    //Previous option value
    'prevPageLabel' => '&nbsp;',
    //Next option value
    'nextPageLabel' => '&nbsp;',
    //Current Active option value
    'activePageCssClass' => 'p-active',
    //Max count of allowed options
    'maxButtonCount' => 8,

    // Css for each options. Links
    'linkOptions' => ['class' => ''],
    'disabledPageCssClass' => 'disabled',

    // Customzing CSS class for navigating link
    'prevPageCssClass' => 'p-back',
    'nextPageCssClass' => 'p-next',
    'firstPageCssClass' => 'p-first',
    'lastPageCssClass' => 'p-last',
]);
```